# How to adjust the default sequence configuration settings in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, sequence

Is there any way to adjust the settings of the default sequence generator? (I mean the sequence generator that takes values from "hibernate_sequence") Specifically:

- Name
- Allocation size
- Optimization strategy

The only thing I've found about this topic is an open Hibernate ticket regarding the default name: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2637

Please note, I'd like to adjust the **default** that's used when I simply specify @GeneratedValue on the ID, and not specify something separately for each @Entity.